# My redirect in .htaccess isn't working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using .htaccess in my public_html folder to redirect my folders to gets:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?v=$1&t=$2

It is giving me a 404 error though when I type my page:

http://southeast.tv/1/e

But it should redirect to:

http://southeast.tv/index.php?v=1&t=e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(\/)?([^/]+)? index.php?v=$1&t=$3
```

Comment: try to add root dir (like http:/.../) before index.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have all of these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])/?([^/])/?$ index.php?v=$1&t=$2
```

Comment: Ok, now it is going to my codeigniter and I'm getting a codeigniter 404, so it must be hitting index.php somehow.